# Evaluating Area Using Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate the area of a triangle $(1,1),(2,5),(3,4)$ using Green's theorem

Using Green's theorem we will evaluate a line integral.

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\gamma}-ydx+xdy$$

The closed curve, anticlockwise is:

$A = (1,1), B = (3,4), C = (2,5)$

$AB=(1+2t,1+3t),t\in[0,1]$

$BC=(3-t,4+t),t\in[0,1]$

$CA=(2-t,5-4t),t\in[0,1]$

$A=\frac{1}{2}\big(\int_{AB}+\int_{BC}+\int_{CA}=\int_0^1\big)$

$$\int_{AB}=\int_0^1(-1-3t,1+2t)\cdot(2,3)dt=\int_0^1dt=1$$

$$\int_{BC}=\int_0^1(-4-4,3-t)\cdot(-1,1)dt=7\int_0^1dt=7$$

$$\int_{CA}=\int_0^1(-5+4t,2-t)\cdot(-1,-4)dt=-3\int_0^1dt=-3$$

So $$A= \frac{1}{2}*5=2.5$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

To verify it, [calculate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates) $\dfrac12\left|\det\begin{pmatrix}2-1&5-1\\3-1&4-1\end{pmatrix}\right|.$